# how to use openssh keys with paramiko

Tags: paramiko

I have a private key as

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How to use this

```
import paramiko
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
key = paramiko.OPENSSHKey.from_private_key_file('/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')
ssh_client.connect(hostname="xx.xx.xx.xx",username='user',pkey=key)
```

It says

```
AttributeError: module 'paramiko' has no attribute 'OPENSSHKey'
```

I tried

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

I get

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
```

Comment: so if i upgrade paramiko, it should solve the problem

Comment: after upgrading to `2.7.2` version, now `key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')` runs without any error, thanks

Comment: did it. given upvote